# Oracle.DataAccess TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a development PC with two versions of Oracle installed i.e. 10g and 11g.

I have a web application (ASP.NET with Visual Basic).  When I deploy the web application to IIS7 (installed on my local PC), both versions work.  However, when I attempt to use them in Visual Studio I receive an error: "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".  I get a reply when I use MSDOS to TNSPING the data source.

Comment: I assume you're trying to use the cassani web server to debug with in visual studio? Are the connection strings the same between visual studio and IIS?

Comment: @Andrew Walters, I am using the web server that is integrated into Visual Studio (is this Cassini?).  Yes, the connection strings are identical.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that locally and in IIS are trying to use different drivers. Could you check that your TNSNames.ora file is included in both the 10G and 11g install paths?

Comment: The TNS names files are identical.